# Is it easier to break into the military base at night?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

In GTA Online I was flying around the military base (Fort Zancudo) in a helicopter at night, looking for what vehicles are there. I thought that flying over the base would make me wanted, so I carefully stayed outside. When I spotted fighter jets I decided to risk it and flew over the base, but didn't gain any wanted level! So I flew around for a few minutes, and only got 4-stars when I landed. It was pretty easy to run to the jet, kill a soldier who spawned next to it and fly off.

From what I've read, breaking into the base should be a lot more difficult. Was this just a one-off, or is it easier to break in during the night (or something else)?

Comment: It's possible, yes. I know for one, that if you drive in without any of the soldiers seeing you (in singleplayer) you can get inside without getting a wanted level. If there are less soldiers during the night, then breaking in should indeed be easier then. Getting out without losing your jet is going to be more difficult, though.

Comment: The Base in GTA: Online is much easier to get into than in GTA 5 singleplayer.

Comment: @5pike Really? Guess it's time for me to give GTA Online another chance then. I just hope I can get in **and** play the *first* mission this time.

Comment: So the wanted level comes from being spotted, rather than being in a 'no-fly' zone?

Comment: @Nolonar - Yeah, it's much easier. In online, the wanted level doesn't trigger as fast as in singleplayer (you can hover over the base to get a good look) and they won't fire anti-air missiles at you. Once you get a wanted level, beware of tanks - they can still easily shoot you off the sky.

Comment: @Ric When you're in the no-fly zone, they'll spot you on their radar.

Comment: there are less tanks at night

Answer (score 2):

I don't think day/night makes any difference.

I've flown into the base multiple times (day and night) and have always gotten the same reaction. You have to fly close enough to the ground inside the base perimeter to trigger the wanted level of 4 stars. If you hover high enough above the base they do not seem to care.

In any case, it seems like landing a helicopter near a jet is the easiest way to obtain one.

Answer (score 0):

There is another easy way all you have to do is get any car and drive south of the base and then jump the small hill on the right side of the tunnel and you will get 4 stars but if you go to the top left of the airbase and circle that end of the runway all the U.S marines will go there except the tanks after that go full speed and get the vehicle you want and fly straight up and then you should be able to loose the police.